# Dynamic organizational chart in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, database, winforms, organizational-chart

I want to create a dynamic organizational chart in windows forms c# which draws data from mdb or sql database with insert/delete/update node options.(I want to do insert,delete,update not by external buttons but minibuttons near to nodes.) Is there any tutorial, sample project you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some free stuff, you can take a look on:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20508/Tree-Chart-Generator

If you have some money to spend, there is also this kind of control in most of paid components package.